# Unable to insert null checks when using HAVING clause while building Spring Data JPA Specifications

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, specifications

My code is currently working using the query below and I am converting the query to JPA Specification.

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT h, SUM(m.annualIncome) " +
        "FROM Household h LEFT JOIN h.familyMemberList m " +
        "GROUP BY h.id " +
        "HAVING SUM(m.annualIncome) < 100000 " +
        "AND (:householdSize IS NULL OR COUNT(m) = :householdSize) " +
        "AND (:householdIncome IS NULL OR SUM(m.annualIncome) = :householdIncome)")
List<Household> findGrantEligibleHouseholds(@Param("householdSize") long householdSize, @Param("householdIncome") long householdIncome);
```

This is what I have done so far which is working but in an unclean manner.

```
public static Specification<Household> grantEligibleHouseholdsSpecification(HouseholdCriteria criteria) {
    return Specification.where(
        (root, query, builder) -> {
            List<Predicate> searchCriteria = new ArrayList<>();
            final Join<Household, FamilyMember> householdFamilyMemberJoin = root.join(Household_.familyMemberList, JoinType.LEFT);
            if(criteria.getHousingType() != null) {
                searchCriteria.add(builder.equal(root.get(Household_.housingType), criteria.getHousingType()));
            }
            query.groupBy(root.get(Household_.id));
            if(criteria.getHouseholdIncome() != null && criteria.getHouseholdSize() != null) {
                query.having(builder.lt(builder.sum(householdFamilyMemberJoin.get(FamilyMember_.annualIncome)),100000)
                        ,builder.equal(builder.count(householdFamilyMemberJoin),criteria.getHouseholdSize())
                        ,builder.equal(builder.sum(householdFamilyMemberJoin.get(FamilyMember_.annualIncome)),criteria.getHouseholdIncome()));
            }
            else if(criteria.getHouseholdIncome() != null) {
                query.having(builder.lt(builder.sum(householdFamilyMemberJoin.get(FamilyMember_.annualIncome)),100000)
                        ,builder.equal(builder.sum(householdFamilyMemberJoin.get(FamilyMember_.annualIncome)),criteria.getHouseholdIncome() ));
            }
            else if(criteria.getHouseholdSize() != null) {
                query.having(builder.lt(builder.sum(householdFamilyMemberJoin.get(FamilyMember_.annualIncome)),100000)
                        ,builder.equal(builder.count(householdFamilyMemberJoin),criteria.getHouseholdSize()));
            }
            else {
                query.having(builder.lt(builder.sum(householdFamilyMemberJoin.get(FamilyMember_.annualIncome)),100000));
            }
            query.multiselect();
            return builder.and(searchCriteria.toArray(new Predicate[searchCriteria.size()]));
        }
    );
}
```

How do I improve this code so in the future it can accept more criteria without going through so many null checks like this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use same approach as for `searchCriteria` - collect multiple predicates into list:

```java
final List<Predicate> havingPredicates = new ArrayList<>();

// default predicates

havingPredicates.add(builder.lt(
        builder.sum(householdFamilyMemberJoin.get(FamilyMember_.annualIncome)), 
        100000));

// custom predicates

if (criteria.getHouseholdIncome() != null) {
    havingPredicates.add(builder.equal(
            builder.sum(householdFamilyMemberJoin.get(FamilyMember_.annualIncome)),
            criteria.getHouseholdIncome()));
}

if (criteria.getHouseholdSize() != null) {
    havingPredicates.add(builder.equal(
            builder.count(householdFamilyMemberJoin),
            criteria.getHouseholdSize()));
}

query.having(havingPredicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works! May I also ask how do you do an OR in having clause?

Comment: @ISSACLIU again it's the same approach. You collect some predicates (for `HAVING`) and then combine them into single predicate using `builder.or(...)`

Comment: Alright. thanks man! I'm slowly getting the hang of it.